# Since $K/F$ is Galois, every embedding of $K$ fixing $F$ is an automorphism of $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to read a proof in Dummit and Foote of the statement

> Suppose $K/F$ is a Galois extension and $F'/F$ is any extension.  Then $KF'/F'$ is a Galois extension, and $Gal(KF'/F') \cong Gal(K/K \cap F')$.

One line I am confused about is

> Since $K/F$ is Galois, every embedding of $K$ fixing $F$ is an automorphism of $K$, so the map $\varphi: Gal(KF'/F') \to Gal(K/F$), $\sigma \mapsto \sigma\vert_K$ defined by restricting an automorphism $\sigma$ to the subfield $K$ is well-defined.

I take it this means automorphisms of $KF'$ fixing $F'$ (thus fixing $F$) also send $K$ to $K$?  If that's what it means, why is it true?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right in your guess. 
Every $\sigma_K$ defines an embedding of $K$ to the bigger field field $KF'$. To show that $\varphi$ is well-defined, you need to show $\sigma(K)=K$ (as sets).  That's the meaning the first sentence in your quotation. As for why, $K/F$ is Galois, in particular, it is normal.  Take any $\alpha \in K$, any embedding fixing $F$ must sends it to a conjugate of $\alpha$. Being normal, $K$ contains all such conjugates.

Comment: You might find useful reading [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35429/galois-group-of-the-product-of-two-fields-being-the-product-of-galois-groups) simplified version of this theorem I asked about in the past. The proof carries through to your generalized version.

Comment: Clever, thanks :)

Comment: @JiangweiXue How did you know that the $K/F$ is algebraic because if $K/F$ is Galois and algebraic then only it is normal.