# Finding the Galois group of a factorized polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

How can I find the Galois group of $(x^2-2)(x^3+x+1)$?

I read the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45893/how-to-find-the-galois-group-of-a-polynomial) for techniques but I didn't find anything about the product of two polynomials.

For the first factor the group is clearly $Z_{2}$, but I can't see it for the second one (how does it help that it has exactly one real root?). Is it generally true that the product of two irreducibles has a Galois group that is the direct sum of the factors?

Comment: Think about the composite of the splitting fields of each of the polynomials.  Check this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35429/254075